# MS MIP SDK 1.11.72 file_sample "Segmentation fault" on CentOS 7

Tags: microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

When I run following command with real credentials to get labels I see "Segmentation fault"

```
./file_sample --clientid fff --username fff@fff --password '!fff -l
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f63b445d980 in TLSv1_2_enc_data () at /lib64/libssl.so.10
#1  0x00007f63b4232a9d in SSL_CTX_new () at /lib64/libssl.so.10
#2  0x00007f63b3491782 in boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method) (this=0x7f637efec200, m=boost::asio::ssl::context_base::sslv23) at /usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/context.ipp:265
#3  0x00007f63b3495d01 in web::http::client::details::asio_connection::upgrade_to_ssl(std::function<void (boost::asio::ssl::context&)> const&) (this=0x7f6388000b10, ssl_context_callback=...)
    at src/external/cpprestsdk/src/http/client/http_client_asio.cpp:137
```

The issue is reproducible. file_sample is buildable. I guess the issue could be related to MS cpprestsdk.
The same command works fine on Debian 10, MacOS 10.15.7.

I have latest CentOS 7

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 5 16:57:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And following dependencies

```
Python 2.7.5
boost169.x86_64                      1.69.0-2.el7              @epel
devtoolset-7-gcc-c++.x86_64          7.3.1-5.16.el7            @centos-sclo-rh
gdk-pixbuf2.x86_64                   2.36.12-3.el7             @base
glib2-devel.x86_64                   2.56.1-9.el7_9            @updates
libcurl-devel.x86_64                 7.29.0-59.el7_9.1         @updates
libgsf.x86_64                        1.14.26-7.el7             @base
libuuid-devel.x86_64                 2.23.2-65.el7_9.1         @updates
libxml2-devel.x86_64                 2.9.1-6.el7_9.6           @updates
openssl.x86_64                       1:1.0.2k-25.el7_9         @updates
python2-scons.noarch                 3.1.2-1.el7               @epel
```

Thank you,
Alexey

Comment: Turns out MS MIP SDK 1.11.72 does not support OpenSSL 1.0 which is the only officially supported version on RHEL 7 / CentOS 7. MS MIP SDK works under OpenSSL 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

MS MIP SDK 1.11.72 does not support OpenSSL 1.0 which is the only officially supported version on RHEL 7 / CentOS 7.
MS MIP SDK works under OpenSSL 1.1